# What are wrong with my SQL queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to implement these queries to my sql, however I don't seem to find what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help please?

```
Application(Id, Name, ShortName)
Uses(ApplicationId, ModuleId)
Module(Id, Name, LinesOfCode, Status)
# The status of a module can be alpha or beta.
# An alpha module is usually an early release with more
# risk that there is an error than for a beta release.
Function(Id, Name, ModuleId, LinesOfCode)
```

List all applications that do not use any module with status alpha.

My Query:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM Application INNER JOIN Uses ON Application.Id = ApplicationId 
    WHERE ModuleId IS NOT (Select Module.Id FROM Module WHERE Status = "Alpha")
```

List all applications that use a module with status alpha and a module with status beta.

My Query:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM Application INNER JOIN Uses ON Application.Id = ApplicationId 
    WHERE ModuleId = (SELECT Module.Id FROM Module WHERE Status = "Beta") 
          AND ModuleId = (SELECT Module.Id FROM Module WHERE Status = "Alpha");
```

Comment: What is your question?  If the queries are not working, then sample data and desired results would help -- as would a single question.

Comment: Try:  `WHERE ModuleId NOT IN (Select Module.Id FROM Module WHERE Status = "Alpha")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can you **NOT IN**  there is not **IS NOT** function in MySQL

```
SELECT * 
        FROM Application INNER JOIN Uses ON Application.Id = ApplicationId 
        WHERE ModuleId  NOT IN (Select Module.Id FROM Module WHERE Status = "Alpha")
```

and 
Seeing your this query you may get more than one id so you should use `IN` instead of `=`

```
SELECT * 
    FROM Application INNER JOIN Uses ON Application.Id = ApplicationId 
    WHERE ModuleId IN (SELECT Module.Id FROM Module WHERE Status = "Beta") 
          AND ModuleId IN (SELECT Module.Id FROM Module WHERE Status = "Alpha");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Application INNER JOIN Uses ON Application.Id = ApplicationId 
WHERE ModuleId NOT IN (Select Module.Id FROM Module WHERE Status = "Alpha")

SELECT * 
FROM Application INNER JOIN Uses ON Application.Id = ApplicationId 
WHERE ModuleId IN (SELECT Module.Id FROM Module WHERE Status = "Beta") 
      AND ModuleId IN  (SELECT Module.Id FROM Module WHERE Status = "Alpha");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Application A 
INNER JOIN Uses U ON (A.Id = U.ApplicationId)
INNER JOIN Module M ON (A.Id = M.Id)
WHERE M.Status  IN ('Beta','Alpha');
```

It gives all columns. You can use alias and pull required column